# Geopandas to locate which area does a point contains

Tags: geopandas

So i have one geodataframe file containing all points in the city while another geodataframe file containing polygon files. With this, is there any other way for me to determine if a point is within a polygon without using sjoin? Since whenever i used this function, this error always appear

'AttributeError: 'BlockManager' object has no attribute 'dtype''

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your point is within a polygon:
`point.within(polygon)`